# New Door Handle wants larger main hole than is on there already

Tags: doors

The new door handle wants a larger hole, by 1/4 inch, than is on there.  What to do?   get a different door handle hoping for the right size hole, or , a new door???

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using the Related postings prior, and removed the anti-pry plate by prying it off.  Oh, the irony.  Thx, SE et al.  Those lever type door handles are the bomb.

Comment: It'd be great to have some more info here, e.g. some pictures, to help others as you've also been helped.

Comment: Camera broke weeks ago.   Need to get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference for someone that may actually be in this situation.

You can get some types of holesaw arbor that will nest/stack within each other. You can then use the inner holesaw as the guide for the outer larger size.

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/319vUomeGjL._SX425_.jpg]

Otherwise you could make up a jig/template, like say for example a simple one would be drill out a piece of scrap wood with the larger size hole and then clamp or temporarily fix it to the door. Then use this scrap piece as a guide.

Comment: good idea on the scrap wood.